# Wrapping long text in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, html-table, word-wrap

I have a problem... I have some long hyperlinks that are plain text that I need to wrap... I've looked for hour and haven't found a way that successfully does it on both Firefox and Internet Explorer. It works fine on Firefox, no problems, but on IE it stretches the table.

I could really use some help to fix this.

Here is the CSS I have, though it says word-wrap isn't valid, I've also tried doing `table-layout:fixed`.

```
.wordwrap
{
    display:inline-block;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

and here is the code in the aspx.cs file

```
tr = new TableRow();
tc = new TableCell();
tc.ColumnSpan = 4;
tc.CssClass = "title";
tc.Text = "Comments";
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
table.Rows.Add(tr);

for (int i = 0; i < dv.Count; i++)
{
    tr = new TableRow();
    tc = new TableCell();
    tc.ColumnSpan = 4;
    tc.Wrap = true;

    tc.CssClass = "wordwrap";
    if (Request.QueryString["edit"] == null)
        tc.Text = dv[i]["fulldescription"].ToString();
    else
    {
        tc.Text = "<a href=\"editComment.aspx?id=" + dv[i]["id"].ToString() + "&oid=" + Request.QueryString["id"]
                        + "&aid=" + dr["id"].ToString() + "&edit=1\">" + dv[i]["fulldescription"].ToString() + "</a>";
                }

    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    table.Rows.Add(tr);
}
```

If you need anything else, let me know...really all I care about is the if part working for now.. that's the part the customer sees.

Edit:
edited generated html

```
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="title">Comments</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td colspan="4">These are some words that are displayed for this comment http://www.themostaweseomesthyperlinkeverbecauseitneverends.com/index.htm.</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td colspan="4">These are some words that are displayed for this commnet with more http://www.uab.edu/......./.</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td colspan="4">These are some words that are displayed for this commnet with more and maybe more http://www.themostaweseomesthyperlinkeverbecauseitneverendsdaskldklkdaskdkjldkljalkjsdkljdslkjdskljkljdsakljdskjldsakljlkjdsakljsdakljsdalkjdskljsdalkjlkjdsalkjsdaklsdalksdalksdlkjdslkjsldkjslkjdajalkasdkljlkjdsalkjdsalkjdsalkjadslkjlkjsdalkjdsalkjdsalkjdsalkjlkdsalkjdsalkjdaslkjsadklakdsakldsjdslakdjjldksdjdklslskdjdakldlkdajkdljkdajkdjkdjalkkdjlkajdlkjadjdajdajkdakjdaadljdakjadjdkjkadlkjdaljkdalkjadklkldajlkjdalkjdalkjdalkjdalkjdalkjdkajlkdadaklkdalkjdalkjdlkjdalkjdakldkajldkjalkjdaldkjalkjdalkjdalkjdakljdalkjdalkjljkadlkjdalkjdalkjlkdjalkjdadjalkldjalkjadadkjlkljdadjlkdlakjkljdakaljdlkjdalkjdakjladljkadkaldjlkjdakljadkjldalkkljdadakdakljkladjl.com/index.htm</td>

</tr><tr>                          
    <td colspan="4">Theehese are some words that are displayed for this commnet with more and maybe morhese are some words that are displayed for this commnet with more and maybe morhese are some words that are displayed for this commnet with more and maybe morhese are some words that are displayed for this commnet with more and maybe more and more</a></td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the class on the A tag (instead of the TD), and then only setting `word-wrap: break-word;`?

This works for me in a test docuemnt in IE 7-9, as well as in Chrome and FF.

Comment: sorry..the A tag shouldnt even be there..just re-edited it..there is no hyperlinks in the customer's report ..i accidentally copied it from the one i see ..not they see..everything is same..except..they cant do hyperlinks

Comment: do you think setting   tc.Text = "<div style=\"word-wrap: break-word;\"> " + dv[i]["fulldescription"].ToString() + " </div> ";

Comment: It might, but I've had much less consistent results when applying `word-wrap` on block-level elements.  If it doesn't work on the DIV, you might try using it on a `<span>` tag since it's a generic inline element.

Comment: what i said totally worked...i've been trying to insert a div for the last hour or so..and couldnt think of how..but your answer had me relooking at the part of the code you were talking about..and i made the changes..and it got it close enough..that it works..thanks so much

Comment: Great; glad to hear that you worked it out! I can't tell you how many times a solution has come to me after stepping away from the problem and gaining fresh perspective. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

[dump generic answer here]

Add `table-layout: fixed` to your table, and then put a `<colgroup>` before the `<tbody>` with `<col>` elements each with `style="width: whatever;"` with whatever you want there.

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 50px;" />
        <col style="width: 400px;" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Long content here, but it gets limited to 50px wide.</td>
            <td>This cell is 400px wide.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't give a more specific answer unless I see some generated HTML.

Comment: You just posted some rows. that doesn't help diagnose the whole table. For example, right now I would assume you're into redundancy, since every single table cell has `colspan="4"`.

Comment: its not a problem with the whole table..it is literally that section in comments..whole table is 4 columns...only the section i gave you has a colspan of 4...if you need more it will take me a bit since i'm about to leave work and run errands...and i'd have to re-edit more text later tonight..but if remove the comment section..table displays perfectly..if i force put spaces..it displays correctly..but because all data is entered by other people..and i cant check every one..so..looking for a way to force break it, but i'll work on a bigger generated html tonight

Comment: You may be better off, then, by having a separate table element for the comments, if possible, or have one table cell with each comment in a `div` with the appropriate width setting.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your table cell (Working in IE 9)

```
.wrapText
{
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    word-wrap:normal;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```